# How do I create dynamic parameters for Chrome extensions?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm bundling a Chrome extension along with a software.
During the installation I'm creating a User ID and writing it in the registry.
I want my extension to "know" this value too, Can I do it without NPAPI plugin?

Comment: A Chrome extension cannot read from the Windows registry. Try the [Storage API](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html) to save values persistently.

Comment: Thanks Rob but I don't see a way to write into Chrome Storage from outside the browser...

Answer (score 0):

If you have a web-site for your product, you can do the following. During installation submit new `UserID` to your site (in addition to writing it into the Registry), then open in Chrome a specific page on your site, which should contain the same `UserID` in parameters. Your extansion can read outgoing requests, so it can parse out the `UserID`. Next it should check response from your server, which must compare `UserID` value obtained from the browser and the one obtained earlier from your installation. This will prevent `UserID` spoofing.

Also, though I'm not sure you'll not consider next suggestion as an *overkill* (so NPAPI plugin looks like acceptable solution as well), but here is how I made a binding between a Chrome extension and external program (for some much more sophisticated purposes than just reading the Registry).

You can build a minimal local web-server (or websockets server) processing requests on a dedicated port, provide it with registration information (`UserID`, etc), and then request required data from the extension just by means of ordinary http-request (for example, AJAX, or websockets client).

The methods have a drawback related to the need to setup user's firewall, so it would allow traffic either from your installer, or from local web-server.